# Div is not expanding with text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
    .row {
        display: flex;
    }
    
    .col {
        flex: 1;
    }
    
    .container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: blue;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #87909A;
        width: 275px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        height: 70px;
    }
    
    .textview {
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 35px;
        padding-left: 13px;
        position: relative;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #CFD4D9;
        background-color: #FFF;
        color: #5C6570;
        padding-right: 13px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .middle {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="event.css">
        </head>
    
        <body>
            <div class="row">
                <div class=".col">
                    <img src="map.png" style="height: 300px; width: 300px; margin-top: 20px;">
                </div>
                <div class=".col">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="textview">
                            <span class="middle">Some text</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="textview">
                            <span class="middle">Some text</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I want to create a view like this but I have something like that above? Can someone let me know how I can center the white container view in the blue background and how to center a text within the white container view.

Also can you give me general feedback if this is the correct way to achieve the layout below? I want to create side by side views where the map is 70% and the right hand side takes up 30%.

[image]

Comment: `class=".col"` is probably a typo, should by `class="col"`

Comment: You want the 2 white boxes, horizontally centered within the blue background?  Looks like you already got the text centered within the white box.

Comment: Check updated answer i added some description to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add following css changes and remove `.` from `col` class in html.

if you need that map will occupy `70%` then use two separate `divs` like `col-1` and `col-2` and assign them `.col-1 {flex:1 0 70%;}` and `col-2 {flex:1 0 30%;}` I added fiddle to better understand.

**[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/2v1pbqL3/1/)**

```
.container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content:center; /* Added */
        background-color: blue;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #87909A;
        width: 275px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        height: 70px;
    }

    .textview {
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 35px;
        padding-left: 13px;
        position: relative;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #CFD4D9;
        background-color: #FFF;
        color: #5C6570;
        padding-right: 13px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: inline-flex; /* Added */
        justify-content:center; /* Added */
        align-items:center; /* Added */
    }
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  flex: 1;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #87909A;
  width: 275px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  height: 70px;
}

.textview {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding-left: 13px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CFD4D9;
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #5C6570;
  padding-right: 13px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.middle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <img src="map.png" style="height: 300px; width: 300px; margin-top: 20px;">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="textview">
        <span class="middle">Some text</span>
      </div>
      <div class="textview">
        <span class="middle">Some text</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style>
body, .container{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    }
.col-1{ width:70%;
        float:left;
      }
.col-2{ width:30%;
        float:left;
      }
```

If the above code doesnt work.
try adjusting the widths to 68%-30% or 65%-30%

Answer (score 0):

Put the two divs with the `textview` class into a parent div.  Then give the parent div a `margin:auto`

```
<div class="parent" style="margin: auto;">
        <div class="textview">
            <span class="middle">Some text</span>
        </div>
        <div class="textview">
            <span class="middle">Some text</span>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
 margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is easier using bootstrap.

import bootstrap to your head and css

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap-grid.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .items{
            height: 60px;background-color: white;
            margin-top: 30px;
        }
        .col1{
            height: 400px;
            background-color: blue;
        }
        .col2{
            height: 400px;
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

then try reading about Bootstrap Grid soo easy

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7 col1">
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col2" >
            <div class="items">
                <p>tex text text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="items">
                <p>tex text text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="items">
            <p>tex text text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Should look how you want it [image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vys5Y.png)